# Is there a limit on how many devices can access the asynchronous webserver of an ESP32?

Tags: arduino, iot, esp32, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to make an easy access ESP32 asynchronous webserver where people within the office network can check the device and give it a set of commands. First few tests with my mobile device and laptop worked quite well but as of now there seems to be only me who can access the webserver's IP.

I have an assumption why this is: it could be because I use my personal access ID and password for the WiFi network on both mobile device and laptop.

Another assumption is that there is a limit on how many devices the ESP32 can respond to.

Does anybody have experience with this? I certainly can't find anything with basic googling, probably because I don't know the specific issue.

Comment: Is the ESP32 set up as an AP or is it part of the office network with an IP address in the range of that network? What library are you using for the webserver bit?

Comment: The ESP32 is set up to be part of the office network with an IP address in the range of the network. The libraries 
used are:

- esp_wpa2.h

- WiFi.h

- ESPAsyncWebServer.h

- SPIFFS.h

- HTTPClient.h

Comment: You say you have a personal access ID, is it a WPA-enterprise network? Then it could have something to do with the settings allowing users to access resources based on permissions.

Comment: It is indeed a WPA-enterprise network. If you think its connected to that, is there a way to change that setting? Do i have to edit the library for that or just change smth in the code?

Comment: It may require hacking into the RADIUS server to authorise all users for accessing the ESP32. If there is some permission set that only allows one to access specific servers and computers with the same login credentials, then only you can access the ESP32. I only know vaguely how access to resources is set up in WPA-enterprise networks, but your system administrator should know (they may be angry with you for introducing a server into their network, though.) You could try if you can access a coworker's computer over the network to see if they manage access to resources.

Comment: Seems like I have to contact the tech people then. I wouldn't want to be a disturbance in the network with this. Thanks for letting me know and finally come closer with my goal!

Comment: Good luck and comment here / let me know if I'm right about this, so I can turn it into an answer.

Comment: Our tech team is notoriously slow so don't hope for a fast answer. Hope to get one at least hehe but yes, ill let you know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want may require hacking into the RADIUS server to authorise all users for accessing the ESP32.

If there is some permission set that only allows one person to access specific servers and computers that have the same login credentials, then only you can access the ESP32.

I only know vaguely how access to resources is set up in WPA-enterprise networks, but your system administrator should know (they may be angry with you for introducing a server into their network, though).

You could try if you can access a coworker's computer over the network to see if they manage access to resources.

Comment: Talking to the system admin was able to solve the problem, he can grant access to everybody to the webserver. A form must be completed in my case. Thanks again for the help! Greately appreciated!